# How to map list of entities to single entity with only unique columns using Streams API?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a situation where i have to join two tables which OneToMany mapping.
I want to know is there an API in java 8 Stream which can create single entity with columns from left table are normal members and right table as list of values.

Example Data:

Table 1

```
id    name 
1     abc
```

Table 2

```
id table1_id note  
1  1         qwerty
2  1         asdfgh
3  1         zxcvbn
```

Joining these two tables. I get something like this

```
select name, note from table1 join table2 on table2.table1_id=table1.id;
abc qwerty
abc asdfgh
abc zxcvbn
```

Current output java object is List of following class

```
class NotesComments{
    String name;
    String notes;
}
```

Expected output is one java class with multiple notes :

```
class NotesComments{
    String name;
    List<String> notes;
}
```

Comment: I know i can use groupingBy if its one column which is unique. But there are more than one colum from first table whose values are unique

Comment: Start from writing the basic `for` loop version of your code and then frame it using streams if really practical. Do define data structures to represent the data you've shared in the question. Aside: What if table 1 have another entry as : `1 , xyz` and  `1, pqr` as well?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @Naman in table1 id is primary key so there is no way that will happen

Answer (score 0):

You can use java - 8 based collectors API to do this.

You can see this example

```
class Table2 {

    int id;
    int table1_id;
    String note;

    public Table2(int id, int table1_id, String note) {
        this.id = id;
        this.table1_id = table1_id;
        this.note = note;
    }


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getTable1_id() {
        return table1_id;
    }

    public void setTable1_id(int table1_id) {
        this.table1_id = table1_id;
    }

    public String getNote() {
        return note;
    }

    public void setNote(String note) {
        this.note = note;
    }
}


class Table1 {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    Table1(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


}
```

// Table3Final - As you mentioned in your question.

```
        Stream<Table1> table1List = Stream.of(new Table1(1, "abc"));
        Stream<Table2> table2List = Stream.of(new Table2(1, 1, "qwerty"),
                new Table2(2, 1, "asdfgh"),
                new Table2(3, 1, "zxcvbn"));

        Stream<Table3Final> table3GeneratedStream = table1List
                .flatMap(en -> table2List
                        .filter(table2Entry -> en.getId() == table2Entry.getTable1_id())
                        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Table2::getTable1_id, Collectors.mapping(Table2::getNote, Collectors.toList())))
                        .entrySet()
                        .stream()
                        .map(mapEntry -> new Table3Final(en.getName(), mapEntry.getValue())));

        /*System.out.println(table3GeneratedStream.count());*/


        table3GeneratedStream.forEach(entry -> {
            System.out.println("--------------Name---------------------------");
            System.out.println(entry.getName());
            System.out.println("----------------Notes-------------------------");
            entry.notes.forEach(System.out::println);
        });
```

Comment: I think you got my question wrong. There is no 3rd table and i don't want  to fire two queries when i can get results in one query

Comment: If you see the code w.r.t stream operation, it combines multiple streams and give you the collected(grouped) output. If you don’t want to collect the result in stream of table3, you can replace the map operations with the foreach  and print the result.